# ForEach Random Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, youtube

I'm trying to make a script that redirects to a random YouTube video. How would I take the vidKey, put each $vidkey in an array and then randomize that array so you get redirected to a different YouTube video?

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TechTubeCentral/uploads?max-results=25");
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
  $vidKey = substr(strrchr($entry->id,'/'),1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put each key into an array, then [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it when you're done:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TechTubeCentral/uploads?max-results=25");
$vidKeys = array();
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry)
  $vidKeys[] = substr(strrchr($entry->id,'/'),1);

shuffle($vidKeys);
```

Then just pick one entry from it, like `$vidKeys[0]`.

You could also put the results in the database and `ORDER BY RAND()`. On next request you get the video keys from the DB, select and remove an entry from the list (see `array_shift`) and put the list back in the DB. You do this until there are no more video keys, then fire the google query again and so on... This saves your script from querying Google on each page load, and decreases the chances for being redirected to the same video

Comment: Shuffling could be time-intensive on large arrays, better to simply use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Comment: reason I don't do a database is because I want it to use the API so that way I can just create the code and just forget about it

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0; $random_video = mt_rand(1, 25);

  $sxml = simplexml_load_file("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TechTubeCentral/uploads?max-results=25");
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {

    if($random_video==$i++){
  $vidKey = substr(strrchr($entry->id,'/'),1); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in function for selecting a random element (or elements) from an array, [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TechTubeCentral/uploads?max-results=25");
$vidKeys = array();
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry)
    $vidKeys[] = substr(strrchr($entry->id,'/'),1);
$randomVidKey = $vidKeys[array_rand($vidKeys)];
```